# How to filter validate strings based on locale in PHP?

Tags: php, validation, unicode-string

I have seen regular expressions doing string validation for languages that cover basic ASCII characters, but that discriminates other alphabets ex: Chinese, Japanese, Cyrillic, Arabic, etc.

It is for user input on a heavily multilingual site.
I can tell the expected input language, based on that it should restrict input for characters of that alphabet.

Is that even feasible?
Does anybody know an existing library that does this kind of validation?

If the whitelist approach based on locale is not realistic, is there a simple generic blacklist solution to block all or at least the most common special characters? (Those that are not members of any locale's alphabets.)

Thanks for any ideas in advance.

Comment: The word "validate", without further context, is meaningless. What criteria make a given string invalid for you? Can't Japanese users type English letters? Can't Arabic users type western numbers?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback, I was trying to refer to the PHPs filter validate functionality: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php - so when a sting contains dots, commas, hashtags, ampersands, etc that are not actual alphabet characters on a given locale. The fact to prevent Japanese people writing English characters is not important.

Comment: I still cannot see how `FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN`, `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`, `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT`... should be affected by alphabet. Certainly, user can type a FLOAT in e.g. Spanish locale `1.123,56` but I wouldn't call that "string validation". Do you have a specific feature in mind you want to implement?

Comment: Oh, I see. As far as I know there is no FILTER_VALIDATE for language characters, that is the thing I miss. The listed validators are just good examples for something similar. So when you type in your username in Chinese, you might want to use Chinese characters, but I don't want you to put commas, dots, hashtags or anything weird non alphabetical characters in those. Does this explain it better?

Comment: Not sure... You want to allow Unicode usernames but explicitly ban non-word characters? E.g., `丼語注` is valid, `john_smith` is not? And American users can have `john` as username but Chinese users cannot?

Comment: First: yes Second: yes, because the underscore is not an alphabetical character, Third: preferably yes, dont allow mixing different writing systems.

Comment: Getting Unicode right is hard. Even a major service as Spotify decided to allow Unicode user names and [was hacked](https://labs.spotify.com/2013/06/18/creative-usernames/). My advice is that you don't waste time and energy trying to implement arbitrary restrictions that might look sensible in your culture at first sight but in the end will only annoy users. Yes, you definitively need restrictions but they need to be strictly technical and not cultural.

Comment: Thanks for the security advice, probably you can avoid that with having the username only for display and identify users based on their e-mail address. On the other hand this problem being difficult is not over-weighting the importance of the feature.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple task, using a regular expression check against character ranges. For example, `/^[\x{0}-\x{1b}]*$/u` will match a string with characters from ASCII 0 to 27.

So the only real effort is in getting all the Unicode blocks down:

```
<?php
class UnicodeBlockCheck
{
    const ADLAM = [0x1E900, 0x1E95F];
    const AGEAN_NUMBERS = [0x10100, 0x1013F];
    const AHOM = [0x11700, 0x1173F];
    const ALCHEMICAL_SYMBOLS = [0x1F700, 0x1F77F];
    // and so on

    private $block;

    public function __construct($block)
    {
        if (!is_array($block) || $block[1] <= $block[0]) {
            throw new Exception("Bad character range passed!");
        } else {
            $this->block = $block;
        }
    }

    public function isValid($string)
    {
        $st = dechex($this->block[0]);
        $fi = dechex($this->block[1]);
        $pattern = '/^[\x{' . $st . '}-\x{' . $fi . '}]*$/u';
        return preg_match($pattern, $string);
    }
}

$bc = new UnicodeBlockCheck(UnicodeBlockCheck::ALCHEMICAL_SYMBOLS);
if ($bc->isValid("")) {
    echo "Valid characters";
} else {
    echo "Invalid characters";
}
```